# How to get response body of Httpexception

Tags: c#

I am sending a webs request using leaf.xnet which uses httpwebrequests

I am trying to catch the response when it status code is not 200

```
                catch (HttpException ex)
                {
Console.WriteLine(ex.Body) #ex.Body is not a method but i want to read response of 404 400 status codes

                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set IgnoreProtocolErrors = true; in HttpRequest object, so then when HttpExceptions occur it doesn't break into exception, but process as normal response. You can parse the response data and do your stuff.

Comment: Yes this was an old thread.. anyways thanks for taking the time and answering that's the solution, I forgot to update it here

Comment: I also search a lot for this, and recently discover it. If its the solution, please accept it as a solution.